# Which scripture mention about Lord rama eating fruits eaten and bitten by shabri?

Tags: ramayana, rama

Valmikiramayana.net says:

> By the way, where is the scene of Rama eating fruits and eatables bitten and tasted by Shabari? Has this old woman not offered the fruits to the guests, or just said that they are available? We listen many stories and see many pictures telling that she gave many fruits after biting them with her own teeth to test the taste. All that is not in Valmiki Ramayana. This amplification is from Padma Purana. *phalaani ca supakvaani muulaani madhuraaNi ca | svayam aasaadya maadhuryam pariikShya paribhakShya ca | pashcaat nivedayaamaasa raaghaabhyaam dhR^iDhvrataa |*

However this isn't found in padma purana(a verse number would be helpful). Do any other scripture mention about this?

Comment: The answer posted below is partial answer as it answer your "a verse number would be helpful" part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. There is no mention of serving fruits after tasting them in Padma Purana as well. Following are the relevant [verses](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365826.html)

> 267-270. He went to the pious, glorious Śabarī. That best among Viṣṇu’s devotees, seeing Rāma and Lakṣmaṇa, went forth to greet them. Having saluted and seated them on a seat of darbhas, she washed their feet. With her mind full of joy she devoutly worshipped them with fragrant wild flowers. She, of a firm vow, then offered the two descendants of Raghu (viz. Rāma and Lakṣmaṇa) fragrant fruits and sweet roots. (Rāma,) the descendant of Kakutstha, gave her the highest liberation.

I could not find mention of Sabari and Sri Rama anywhere other than Valmiki Ramayana and Padma Purana

Comment: Nice answer. Check this if you understand Hindi [supposed misinterpretation of verse from the Padma purana](https://m.facebook.com/deendayaljemaharaj/posts/988466604688567/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29689)

Comment: @sv - please read the question. He wanted verse number from Padma purana. And I am not saying it is not present elsewhere. I am saying I could not find it.

Comment: But that's not the main question (which is 'Do any other scripture mention about this?'). FYI, someone else flagged this as Not An Answer. I was just reviewing it. Your answer looks like commentary on the question so probably works better as a comment under the question.

Comment: @sv - this has been covered in meta. If the answer is negative , then it would be accurate to say not found by  me in scripture. Otherwise these questions will never have answers and only comments. And I again repeat - the OP asked for verses from Padma Purana that has reference to Sabari